# Why is the European Commission promoting meat consumption?

Tags: environmental-policy, european-commission

According to this [article](https://euobserver.com/climate/151495), the European commission spent 252 million over four years to promote meat and dairy products.

The majority of [research](https://sites.google.com/view/sources-climate-meat/) shows that there are a lot of benefits to less meat consumption. The alternatives are often more cost efficient to produce, and more environment friendly.

It seems to go against some of [goals](https://european-union.europa.eu/principles-countries-history/principles-and-values/aims-and-values_en) of the European Union:

> - protect and improve the quality of the environment
> - promote peace, its values and the **well-being** of its citizens

What are the European commissions reasons for promoting meat consumption?

Comment: I downvoted because the premise of the benefits of less meat consumption are highly speculative and generally pushed by special interests.

Comment: Why would they not be promoting products created in the EU? If anything this sounds like an anti mean/dairy rant to push a vegan diet.

Comment: @JoeW & AlanDev-boycottRussia , I have added a link to sources showing the downside of livestock vs plants. Could you supply me with some counter sources, so I can also add these to my question (I could not find any, but I might be in a bubble).

Comment: This isn't a forum to debate the upsides and downsides of livestock versus plants. At most you can focus on why they are promoting it which can be answered by them promoting products of the EU. I am now voting to close this as an attempt to discredit the consumption of meat and other animal products.

Comment: -1 for "lot of benefits to less meat consumption" => I'm vegetarian but still think that those claims are tenuous at best

Comment: @JoeW I can see where you are coming from with the text of the question, but unless the EU are spending money advertising plant based alternatives to meat as well then it is pretty clearly promoting one option and not another. And honestly it is not like meat needs promoting. Are there really people out there that haven't come across it yet? So at the very least the points Fizz raised about the meat lobby and embedded current practices seem valid.

Comment: @Jontia Is there any evidence that they are not spending money on plant based alternatives? If there was that would be a different question from what is being asked. I would have no reason to think that they are not promoting all their products because there is no reason to not do so.

Comment: @JoeW I should imagine it would be easier to show they are spending money advertising plant based alternatives if that is indeed the case, and it would be a good frame challenge answer to the question. Such a clear prompt led me to this; https://www.safefoodadvocacy.eu/plant-based-put-forward-in-the-eus-2022-promotional-policy/ the referenced 'December Policy' is what I need to find next. As soon as I get in front of a non mobile device... Though it looks like a clear change in policy for 22. Not something in place at the time in discussion in the Question.

Comment: @Jontia Again, that would be a different question then the one being asked now.

Comment: Vote to reopen. I think it is a good faith effort. I ask myself why meat must be advertised for.

Comment: @Trilarion Question might be better without the claim that plants are healthier. The other two points (cost en environment impact) seem to be less debated and still good reasons why eu shouldn't promote meat

Comment: Promoting meet being against the well being of the citizens of the EU is a very questionable claim that many people would question.

Answer (score 14):

The EU has an extensive farming support framework called the [CAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Agricultural_Policy).  It subsidizes lots of things, healthy or not.

First, to your claim.

Moderate meat consumption is not necessarily all that bad for people's health.  Like it or not, humans evolved as omnivores and diets without animal products of any kind need careful tuning to cover all our needs (in parts of the world where this practice is not traditional).

If we put a filter on health, lots of things are overeaten.  Sugar for example, no need to single out meat.  Probably the only under-eaten foods are the healthier food groups like fruits and vegetables.  So, spinach and broccoli-only subsidies?

Meat dishes are an important of many European cultures' culinary heritage (which doesn't necessarily mean it needs to be subsidized).

However, meat consumption, especially of beef/ruminants have a heavy CO2-equivalent footprint associated with them.

On to the CAP itself.  It doesn't draw the line at just meat.  Sugar gets subsidized.  Wine producers.  Heck, even [tobacco farmers](https://ihsmarkit.com/research-analysis/eu-keeps-pumping-100-million-into-tobacco-production.html).

The EU subsidized farmers for years, whether it needed what they produced  or not.  It was famous for [butter mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butter_mountain) and wine lakes, but has since somewhat shifted to direct farmer support rather than volume-based subsidies/guaranteed prices.

**Support to promote or market specific goods is another facet of the EU's complex and evolving mechanisms to support farmers and is *somewhat* better than the even more distorting effects of guaranteed prices.**

In the past, EU subsidized beef got [dumped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumping_(pricing_policy)) on the world market, especially [Africa, hurting local producers](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/report-claims-traders-dump-beef-in-africa-1.224819).  The dumping been stopped - with some/all export subsidies getting withdrawn, but EU meat exports are still [distorting things in Africa](https://www.un.org/africarenewal/magazine/june-2021/african-farmers-could-benefit-more-friendly-eu-agriculture-policies).

Even now, much of the CAP subsidies favor [larger producers](https://eufactcheck.eu/factcheck/true-80-percent-of-the-european-money-for-agriculture-goes-to-the-20-percent-largest-farmers/), rather than the much-romanticized "family farm" (guaranteed-price subsidies tended to make this even worse).

Bottom line:  there are many bizarre and unwanted side-effects from the CAP, promoting meat is only one of them.

Past strategic concerns like food security, or even land management, the CAP, like equivalent programs in other wealthy countries (Canada, USA, Japan, etc...) is big business, politically.  That's a lot of sweet, sweet, pork going out to favored special interest groups and farmers are about as politically influential as special interest groups get.

It's big political horse-trading intra-EU, with certain countries specialized in trying to get the overall EU to pay out the most they can get for their national farmers (cough, France, cough).

**Much of it makes little sense, medically, environmentally and most of all taxpayer-wise.**  Targeting only meat might make this question sound a tad preachy to some, at least if you are as cynical about farming subsidies as I am.

---

p.s. on the health and environment side:

CO2-wise, not all meat is equal.  Chicken and pork are lowest, sitting at [5-10x less than beef](https://www.economist.com/graphic-detail/2021/10/02/treating-beef-like-coal-would-make-a-big-dent-in-greenhouse-gas-emissions).  You don't have to go vegetarian/vegan, but meat is a surprisingly large component of emissions, *easily* 2-4 tons (out of 15 for North Americans).  Taking 30%-50% off most people's diet will have an immediate effect and is likely good for your health too.

Health-wise, maybe consider changing your eating habits, rather than substituting via the new-fangled meat substitutes.  They are not ["food your grandmother knew"](https://www.bbc.com/news/health-58762885), have a long list of ingredients and really don't seem all that healthy.  I *like* Impossible Burgers, for example, but their salt content is pretty shocking.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135185/discussion-on-answer-by-italian-philosophers-4-monica-why-is-the-european-commis).

Answer (score 3):

EU has many meat and diary product producers who need to sell their produce (I mean especially farmers, rather than big corporations). We are talking here about millions of jobs. This reflects on the *well-being* of the European citizens more significantly, than the health and environmental improvements resulting from not consuming these products.

> The majority of research shows that their are a lot of benefits to less meat consumption.
> The alternatives are often healthier, cheaper, and more environment friendly.

These are highly disputable points. Although many people and some scientists do believe this to be the case, it is far from scientific consensus (please provide the relevant references, if I am wrong.)

See:
[Animal products in the EU](https://ec.europa.eu/info/food-farming-fisheries/animals-and-animal-products/animal-products/)
[EU agricultural outlook 2021-31: consumer behaviour to influence meat and dairy markets](https://ec.europa.eu/info/news/eu-agricultural-outlook-2021-31-consumer-behaviour-influence-meat-and-dairy-markets-2021-dec-09_en)

[Farmers and the agricultural labour force - statistics](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Farmers_and_the_agricultural_labour_force_-_statistics):

> People working in agriculture accounted for about 4.2 % of total employment in the EU in 2016 (see Figure 1), corresponding to 9.7 million persons. Agriculture is a particularly big employer in Romania, accounting for just less than one in every four persons (23.0 %) employed in the country, as well as in Bulgaria (17.5 % of total employment), Greece (10.7 %) and Poland (10.1 %).
> [image]

Comment: The contribution of meat production, particularly raising of ruminants, to global warming is well recognised.  To provide a reference for lack of dispute is hard, but the [IPCC report](https://www.ipcc.ch/srccl/) states with high confidence that balanced diets featuring plant-based food "present major opportunities for adaptation and mitigation while generating significant co-benefits in terms of human health" as well as much more. Your economic points are good.

Comment: @User65535 You'd have to point me the specific palce in this report. I am afraid that the effect is either non-existent or small - scientifically speaking. The formulation that you quote is too vague to be a basis for real policy, unlike the numbers on beef and dairy products. FYI: I am not disputing what you say, just trying to reason rigorously.

Comment: I'm sure many people get paid lots of money to make cigarettes. Should the EU promote smoking cigarettes?

Comment: @user253751 good example - indeed, in the case of cigarettes one can demonstrate their negative effects by multiple scientific studies and statistics - the negative effects of meat and dairy consumption are less tangible. I am  sure though that reduction in tabacco consumption had devastating effects in some third world countries.

Comment: @RogerVadim the truth is that any "suppressed" economic activity will be replaced by other economic activity as the free market dictates. Tobacco farmers will not starve - they will grow something else. According to free market principles.

Comment: @user253751 Sure, I also believe in the market economy... but I noticed that every time a factory employing a few hundred people is about to get closed in Europe, employees go out in streets, and the government makes it a priority to avoid closure... It also happens in US, although with larger companies - like General Motors. But my main point is still that real decisions are based on hard numbers: meat, dairy, cigarettes have them, ecological effects of meat and dairy consumption are still mostly much ado about little (I do not say *nothing*).

Comment: A worldwide reduction of [3 to 6 billion tons of CO2 per year](https://www.ipcc.ch/srccl/chapter/chapter-5/#section-5-5-2-demand-side-mitigation-options) is neither "non-existent" nor "small".

Comment: @meriton *not small* compared to what? Note that EU is 250 million people of 8 billion (since you cite *worldwide reduction*). Also, is there a scientific consensus... with the error bar as big as the number itself?

Comment: Not small compared to the total net annual greenhouse gas emissions of 35 billion tons. That diet changes alone could reduce mankinds CO2 emissions by 10% to 20% percent (depending on diet chosen, and strength of economic incentives applied) is not "small" by any reasonable definition of the word.

Comment: ... and no, that difference is not an error bar, but reflects the spread of different diets that were assessed.

Comment: @meriton from my brief search (e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental_impact_of_meat_production#Greenhouse_gas_emissions)) *all livestock and related activities* accound for 14.5-18% of the antropogenic greenhouse emissions, which is inconsistent with your numbers (which deal only with meat and diary production and only dietary changes rather than complete elimination, but give 10-20% of the total). Note that I am agnostic on the issue, but since you chose aggressive tone, cherry-picking words from my previous comments, I am obliged to fight back.

Comment: I'm not an expert either, so I couldn't vouch for single percentage points. I suspect the difference lies in methodology: The IPCC figures include carbon sink effects enabled by reforesting areas no longer needed for agriculture, while the FAO numbers only count present emissions, not the reduction potential that land could have if reforested (for further details, please check the source I provided - a stack exchange comment is too short to express nuance, I'm afraid). Also, the FAO source is 9 years old, the baseline may have changed since.